# how to print all values print outside the loop in android

Tags: java, android

I can fetch the menucode from database i can print inside for loop means it prints all menucodes. if i print loop out side means it print only last value

```
         my code
     JSONArray json = jArray.getJSONArray("mainmenu");

         for ( i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
            map.put("itemcode", e.getString("menucode"));   //here i print all values  


         }
      list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {   

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            System.out.println(map.get("itemcode"));//here i print only last value(here i want print all values how can i do this)
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FoodMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

out side for loop also i want print all menucodes .. please help me

Comment: why do u want to print it outside that loop? if you want to print outside that loop, u need to create another loop and iterate over the JSONArray again, which will be like iterating over the entire  same array twice, once for putting the values in the map, and second loop for printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a map, and you have the same key all the time (`"itemcode"`), so each insertion overrides the previous insertion to the map, maybe you should just use a `List`, or use different keys.

Answering the comment by giving examples:

1. Using `ArrayList` / `List`:

   ```
   List<String> codez = new ArrayList<String>();
   for ( i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
       codez.add(e.getString("menucode"));
   }
   ```
2. Using different keys:

   ```
   for ( i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
       map.put("itemcode" + i, e.getString("menucode"));
   }
   ```

Last thing - you cannot have two identical keys in a map, it defeats its purpose, and it's useless. If you are not going to get the values with by the key, and if the key is not used, you shouldn't use a map in first place.

Comment: i don't want use list . please how to store menucodes in string array.. please replay

Comment: out side loop i print all codes.now i am comparing if(codez.equls("1")) means it navigate one page other wise navigate another page. how can i do using list

Comment: if(codez.equls("1"))  how can i give the codition in list array

Comment: how can you give a condition in map?